# WCF Service reset case sensitive property of Dictionary

Tags: wcf, dictionary, case-sensitive, containskey

i have a Dictionary.
it is most important that this dictionary will use its Containskey() method as **not** case sensitive that is why i use the constructor to make it case insensitive:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> wishProductNames = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            DBService.GetNameAndPhrases(ref wishProductNames);
```

i send it to a WCF service Method to be filled and return.
it works ok but the case sensitive property is reset back to being case sensitive, and i can't set it back because it is only set in creation.

i can always use arrays to get the data from the WCF and then fill the Dictionary and i can always copy the result dictionary to another which is case insensitive , but how do i overcome the property reset issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The comparer associated with the dictionary is not part of the data serialization and deserialization.

You can however easily recreate a dictionary with the same items and the appropriate comparer through the [Dictionary(IDictionary dictionary, IEqualityComparer comparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132073.aspx) constructor overload.